# how to subtract to sum(produced from same table) in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
amount  group
--------------
 100     'a'
  40     'b'
  30     'a'
  50     'b'
```

query output:

```
diff(a-b)
---------
  40
```

how to do it in MYSQL?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please reat the guide how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks  Cid. I was finding to edit to give a good look.

Comment: @by_default check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) about formatting, it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM t WHERE `group` = 'a') -
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM t WHERE `group` = 'b') AS diff
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
           WHEN `group` = 'a' THEN  amount
           WHEN `group` = 'b' THEN -amount
       END) AS diff
FROM t
```